# Olympus Viewer not saving EXIF geotag data in photos?

Tags: software, metadata, olympus, geotagging

in the last few months I have been using Olympus Viewer 3 for my photos (I have a Stylus 1 camera).

I like geotagging, so at the end of a trip, I usally put all my photos together, check the correct geotag data for the one I geologged (using the Olympus Image Share app on a smartphone), and add missing geotag data (for photos I took while the Image Share app was not logging).

I noticed that the geotag EXIF data in photos, is present for the geologged photos, but is not being saved for the manually geotagged photos! I find this very annoying...

I think Olympus Viewer is saving my geotag data in an internal database or somewhere else, since I can view it if I open the photo in the program, but I cannot seem to find a command to save EXIF geotag data to the single .JPG photo files...

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume you are adding geotag with an external software. Are you adding missing geotags *before* importing the images in Olympus Viewer or *after* ? If you are doing it after, you may need to reimport EXIF from your images (if you have this option). If you are doing it before, something is probably amiss in your geotag editing software. You can also open the modified file (with the geotag added) with an EXIF viewer to see if it really has been saved.

Comment: I added geotag in Olympus viewer ("map" window); I can see geotags in Olympus Viewer, but the tags are not in EXIF data, I checked it. I suppose OV is saving geodata somewhere else...

Comment: So you need to find a way to extract the geotag from Olympus Viewer database and store it as sidecar (xmp) or in the EXIF (and you might probably want to use a third party geotagging software for the next images you want to geotag).

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to **export** the photo.

My experience is the same: I load the log file then perform the GPS Log Matching. If I later open one of the relevant photos in OV3 the location info is available in the map view but not the EXIF. Oly Viewer either reads the location info from the log file on the fly or has saved it somewhere other than the EXIF.

**If I export a photo, including by emailing it, OV3 includes the location info in the EXIF.**

(An alternative method is to convert the OIShare log file to GPX using GPS Babel, import it into Garmin Basecamp, and geotag the photos from there.  This does add the location info to the EXIF but only works for jpg files, not orfs.)